# Display data in a GSP page text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have a gsp page with two select drop down. based on the value i select and click the compare button it retrieves the value from the database and does manipulation. (like comparison) if they are same print in the same gsp page as value is same.If they are not same then the value has to be displayed in the index gsp page in two text area side by side with the values.

```
this is my gsp page

   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<title>Json Compare</title>

<g:javascript plugin="jquery" library="jquery" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"/>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.testMe').click(function(){
            var URL="${createLink(controller:'jsonComparison',action:'compare')}";
            alert(URL)
            alert(firstText.value)
            alert(secondText.value)
            $.ajax({
                url:URL,
                data: {firstText:firstText.value,secondText:secondText.value},
                success: function(data){
                    //console.log(resp);

                    $("#result").val(data).show()

                }
            });
        });
    });

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <g:form>
        <div></div><label>From Time</label><g:select name="firstText" from="${eventsList}"  noSelection="['':'-Choose the From Date-']"/> 
        <label>To Time</label><g:select name="secondText" from="${eventsList}"  noSelection="['':'-Choose the To Date-']"/></div>
        <button class="testMe">Compare</button>
        <br>
        <textarea id="result" style="display: none"></textarea>
        <%-- <textarea id="result1" style="display:none"></textarea> <textarea id ="result1" style="display:none"></textarea> --%>
    </g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller. based on the value selected in the index page and click the compare button i am calling a ajax function which calls a controller. In the controller i am passing the selected values and checking from the database whether they are same and based on the response i need to display the message in the index.gsp

```
 class JsonComparisonController {

    def preparedStatementService


    def index() {
        //List eventsList = preparedStatementService.retrieveValuesFromDb()
        def eventsList = ['2017-10-11 04.94.34', '2016-09-11 04.94.44', '2017-10-12 04.94.89']
        render view: 'index', model: [eventsList: eventsList]
    }

    def compare() {
        println "The Compare is called"
        String firstParameter = params.firstText
        String secondParameter = params.secondText
        def returnValue
        println "The first value is: " + firstParameter + "The second value is: " + secondParameter
        if(firstParameter !=null && secondParameter !=null && firstParameter.length() > 0 && secondParameter.length() > 0){
            println "Both the values are not null"
            if(firstParameter.equals(secondParameter)){
                println "First and second values are equal"
                returnValue = "The Json are Equal and no MisMatch"
                render status: 200, text: returnValue
            }else{
                println "The values are not equal"
                String value1 = "The First Json values"
                String value2 = "The Second Json Values"
                render status: 200, model:[firstText:value1,secondText:value2]
            }

        }else{
            render status: 200, text: "Please select the Time"
        }

    }
}
```

how do i receive the response from the controller in the ajax function. and also display the result in the index.gsp page

Answer (score 0):

**Please study and understand fixes in gsp & controller 
this is your gsp fixed:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<title>Json Compare</title>
<g:javascript plugin="jquery" library="jquery" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"/>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.testMe').click(function(){
            var URL="${createLink(controller:'jsonComparison',action:'compare')}";
            alert(URL)
            alert(firstText.value)
            alert(secondText.value)
            $.ajax({
                url:URL,
                data: {firstText:firstText.value,secondText:secondText.value},
                success: function(data){
                  if (data.status===true) {
                     //notice .html since it is content of textArea
                     $('#result1').html(data.result)
                     //if this was <input type=text value="something"
                     //then result would be the value of the form field
                     //$('#result1').val(data.result)
                  } else { /// if (data===false ) {
                        $('#result1').html(data.value1).show()
                        $('#result2').html(data.value2).show()
                  } 
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <g:form>
        <div></div><label>From Time</label><g:select name="firstText" from="${eventsList}"  noSelection="['':'-Choose the From Date-']"/> 
        <label>To Time</label><g:select name="secondText" from="${eventsList}"  noSelection="['':'-Choose the To Date-']"/></div>
        <button class="testMe">Compare</button>
        <br>
        <textarea id="result" style="display: none"></textarea>
        <%-- <textarea id="result1" style="display:none"></textarea> <textarea id ="result1" style="display:none"></textarea> --%>
    </g:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is your controller fixed

```
class JsonComparisonController {

    def preparedStatementService


    def index() {
        //List eventsList = preparedStatementService.retrieveValuesFromDb()
        def eventsList = ['2017-10-11 04.94.34', '2016-09-11 04.94.44', '2017-10-12 04.94.89']
        render view: 'index', model: [eventsList: eventsList]
    }

    def compare() {
        String firstParameter = params?.firstText   //make it nullsafe not going to throw an exception with ?
        String secondParameter = params?.secondText
        def returnValue
        //this is doing exactly what you were doing long winded
        def reply
        if(firstParameter && firstParameter) {
            if (firstParameter == firstParameter ){
                reply=[status:true, result:"The Json are Equal and no MisMatch"]                
            }else{
                reply = [status:false, value1:"The First Json values ${firstParameter}", value2:"The Second Json Values ${secondParameter}"]               
            }
        }else{
            reply = [status:false, value1:"issue here", value2:"issue here"]       
        }
        render status: 200, text:(reply as JSON).toString()
    }
}
```

And rather than having a click me on button you could have

```
$('#secondText').on('change', function() {

 var val = $(this).val();
 var other = $('#firstText').val();
  if (val!='' && other!='') {
var URL="${createLink(controller:'jsonComparison',action:'compare')}";
                alert(URL)
                alert(val)
                alert(other)
                $.ajax({
                    url:URL,
                    data: {firstText:val,secondText:other},
                    success: function(data){
                      if (data.status===true) {
                         //notice .html since it is content of textArea
                         $('#result1').html(data.result)
                         //if this was <input type=text value="something"
                         //then result would be the value of the form field
                         //$('#result1').val(data.result)
                      } else { /// if (data===false ) {
                            $('#result1').html(data.value1).show()
                            $('#result2').html(data.value2).show()
                      } 
                    }
                });
  }
})
```

this then auto triggers upon change of second field

Comment: my problem is i need to display the result in the same gsp page. If they are not equal they they should be displayed in two seperate text area side by side

Comment: once i get the response from the controller that the values are not equal then the text area should be visible and it should print the both values

Comment: i tried the code that you had mentioned above but now my text area is not displayed

Comment: data.status===true not data,success===true as was previously it was my mistake but it clearly shows you don't understand what is going on too well

Comment: i had changed that already and the problem is my textarea is not getting displayed

Comment: also $('#result1').html(entry.result) i changed to $('#result').html(data.result) as my textarea id is result and entry to data

Comment: Ye sorry my bad but at least you get it much tidier than your existing code also captures issue when both are null

Comment: i could not know the reason why my text area is not getting displayed. tried many ways but still no luck. any thoughts